# svg elements for highchart legend

Tags: svg, highcharts

I am using svg  to draw the chart using highcharts and basically want to have the custom legend which can be exported. so we are trying to draw the custom legend for line chart.I just want to have the `<ul><li></li></ul>` using the svg elements and can specify the width in terms of percentage.

Comment: How far have you got and what specifically are you stuck on?

Comment: Basically i need to draw a table with data below below the line chart.So i was successful drawing it using html elements but while exporting they are not visible since they are outside <svg>. So i was trying to create the table using svg elements but was facing issue while setting widths for the text elements. I dont want to use <foreignObject> since it might not be supported in all browsers.

Comment: If what you want is to export the data table or any other HTML table see: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions#add-data-table.